# Grunt Livereload not showing HTML changes

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, mean-stack, livereload

On my MEAN stack application, I'm trying make changes to the HTML view files and see those changes as I make them using Grunt's livereload.

Grunt's livereload is working fine in the sense that it detects changes in my HTML files and refreshes the page during development. However, the actual changes are not reflecting on the page. If I push the files up the server, and reload the publicly available site, the changes are there. But I still can't see the changes while I'm developing.

I'm 99% sure that the problem has to do with the server is using the "build" files or something rather than the files located in the /public folder. However, I'm new to using the back-end and the MEAN stack and can't figure out what file the browser is showing or where this file is. Could anyone give any guidance on how to figure out what file the browser is displaying and what I can do to show HTML changes I make as I make them?

Here is my gruntfile if this helps. The below files I'm making changes to are watchFiles.clientViews.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {
    // Unified Watch Object
    var watchFiles = {
        serverViews: ['app/views/**/*.*'],
        serverJS: ['gruntfile.js', 'server.js', 'config/**/*.js', 'app/**/*.js'],
        clientViews: ['public/modules/**/views/**/*.html'],
        clientJS: ['public/js/*.js', 'public/modules/**/*.js'],
        clientCSS: ['public/modules/**/*.css'],
        mochaTests: ['app/tests/**/*.js']
    };

    // Project Configuration
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        watch: {
            options: { livereload: true },
            serverViews: {
                files: [watchFiles.serverViews],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            serverJS: {
                files: watchFiles.serverJS,
                tasks: ['jshint'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            clientViews: {
                files: watchFiles.clientViews,
                options: {
                    livereload: true,
                }
            },
            clientJS: {
                files: watchFiles.clientJS,
                tasks: ['jshint'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            clientCSS: {
                files: watchFiles.clientCSS,
                tasks: ['csslint'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            }
        },
        jshint: {
            all: {
                src: watchFiles.clientJS.concat(watchFiles.serverJS),
                options: {
                    jshintrc: true
                }
            }
        },
        csslint: {
            options: {
                csslintrc: '.csslintrc',
            },
            all: {
                src: watchFiles.clientCSS
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            production: {
                options: {
                    mangle: false
                },
                files: {
                    'public/dist/application.min.js': 'public/dist/application.js'
                }
            }
        },
        cssmin: {
            combine: {
                files: {
                    'public/dist/application.min.css': '<%= applicationCSSFiles %>'
                }
            }
        },
        nodemon: {
            dev: {
                script: 'server.js',
                options: {
                    nodeArgs: ['--debug'],
                    ext: 'js,html',
                    watch: watchFiles.serverViews.concat(watchFiles.serverJS)
                }
            }
        },
        'node-inspector': {
            custom: {
                options: {
                    'web-port': 1337,
                    'web-host': 'localhost',
                    'debug-port': 5858,
                    'save-live-edit': true,
                    'no-preload': true,
                    'stack-trace-limit': 50,
                    'hidden': []
                }
            }
        },
        ngAnnotate: {
            production: {
                files: {
                    'public/dist/application.js': '<%= applicationJavaScriptFiles %>'
                }
            }
        },
        concurrent: {
            default: ['nodemon', 'watch'],
            debug: ['nodemon', 'watch', 'node-inspector'],
            options: {
                logConcurrentOutput: true,
                limit: 10
            }
        },
        env: {
            test: {
                NODE_ENV: 'test'
            }
        },
        mochaTest: {
            src: watchFiles.mochaTests,
            options: {
                reporter: 'spec',
                require: 'server.js'
            }
        },
        karma: {
            unit: {
                configFile: 'karma.conf.js'
            }
        }
    });

    // Load NPM tasks
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // Making grunt default to force in order not to break the project.
    grunt.option('force', true);

    // A Task for loading the configuration object
    grunt.task.registerTask('loadConfig', 'Task that loads the config into a grunt option.', function() {
        var init = require('./config/init')();
        var config = require('./config/config');

        grunt.config.set('applicationJavaScriptFiles', config.assets.js);
        grunt.config.set('applicationCSSFiles', config.assets.css);
    });

    // Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['lint', 'concurrent:default']);

    // Debug task.
    grunt.registerTask('debug', ['lint', 'concurrent:debug']);

    // Lint task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('lint', ['jshint', 'csslint']);

    // Build task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('build', ['lint', 'loadConfig', 'ngAnnotate', 'uglify', 'cssmin']);

    // Test task.
    grunt.registerTask('test', ['env:test', 'mochaTest', 'karma:unit']);
};
```

In addition, here is the file structure to my MEAN stack. The highlighted below is where the HTML file that I'm making changes to is located.

[image: Imgur]

Please let me know if there is any other code or info I could provide that would make solving this problem easier. Thank you.

**Update: Content of Server.js**

Here is my server.js content:

```
'use strict';
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var init = require('./config/init')(),
    config = require('./config/config'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

/**
 * Main application entry file.
 * Please note that the order of loading is important.
 */

// Bootstrap db connection
var db = mongoose.connect(config.db, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('\x1b[31m', 'Could not connect to MongoDB!');
        console.log(err);
    }
});

// Init the express application
var app = require('./config/express')(db);

// Bootstrap passport config
require('./config/passport')();

// Start the app by listening on <port>
app.listen(config.port);

// Expose app
exports = module.exports = app;

// Logging initialization
console.log('MEAN.JS application started on port ' + config.port);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell exactly what your "server.js" is serving without seeing the contents of it, but if my assumption is correct and you are serving the contents of the "public" directory, you don't have any sort of task being fired by `watch` that facilitates copying the contents of your changed files into your "public" directory.  It looks like this happens initially when your server is started (by running the `build` task), but not run subsequently whenever something is changed.

I would suggest modifying your watch tasks to perform some of the build-related tasks on your files as they are changed.  Since your build-related tasks are physically copying the changes to the "public" directory for you as part of their jobs, you should finally see the results of your changes.  Here's an example of your `watch` task list that's modified to copy your JS and CSS files on change:

```
watch: {
    options: { livereload: true },
    serverViews: {
        files: [watchFiles.serverViews],
        options: {
            livereload: true
        }
    },
    serverJS: {
        files: watchFiles.serverJS,
        tasks: ['jshint', 'loadConfig', 'ngAnnotate', 'uglify'],
        options: {
            livereload: true
        }
    },
    clientViews: {
        files: watchFiles.clientViews,
        options: {
            livereload: true,
        }
    },
    clientJS: {
        files: watchFiles.clientJS,
        tasks: ['jshint', 'loadConfig', 'ngAnnotate', 'uglify'],
        options: {
            livereload: true
        }
    },
    clientCSS: {
        files: watchFiles.clientCSS,
        tasks: ['csslint', 'cssmin'],
        options: {
            livereload: true
        }
    }
},
```

**One last thing:**  Assuming your views don't need to have any modifications done to them post-change, you can simply straight-up copy them to the public directory when they are changed.  Take a look at [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) for doing simple file copying between directories.

Comment: See my addition of the contents of my server.js above. I DON'T think the app is serving the contents of my public folder. I'm editing the contents of the public folder directly, and the changes are not being reflected...

Comment: Also, the best I can tell is that grunt is serving the files in "/app" rather than "public", would I change the gruntfile to reflect this?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and solved it by disabling the cache in the network tab

Go to Inspect -> Network and make sure disable cache is checked.

Hope this helps someone in future :)